# How to create mysql database on existing DB server in puppet class

Tags: mysql, puppet

My puppet agent machine has already installed mysql server. I want to create database on that server. My puppet class is as follows

```
class dbtest {

mysql::db { 'mydb':
user     => 'root',
password => 'malintha',
host     => 'localhost',
}
```

This gives me error `Error: Failed to apply catalog: Could not find dependency Class[Mysql::Server] for Mysql_database[mydb]`

How can I sortout this issue ?  How can I import mysql server dependancy class

Answer (score 0):

I could fix this issue adding`class { '::mysql::server':} to my class`

```
class dbtest {

class { '::mysql::server':}

mysql::db { 'mydb1':
user     => 'root',
password => 'malintha',
host     => 'localhost',
sql        => '/tmp/source.sql',
require => File['/tmp/source.sql'],
}
```